# How get and store max and min value on variables (double)

Tags: c#

I have two `double` variable `realStop, Marze` which changes value every second. I need to get the maximum and minimum value from both and store it to `realStopMax, realStopMin` and `MarzeMax, MarzeMin`.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you need the max/min of `realStop` and `Marze`, or that you need to keep track of the largest/smallest values of those variables over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As every second your value is changing so you need to update the variables likewise:

```
// It will always compare with the previous maximum and minimum values
realStopMin = Math.Min(realStopMin, realStop);
realStopMax = Math.Max(realStopMax, realStop);

MarzeMin = Math.Min(MarzeMin, Marze);
MarzeMax = Math.Max(MarzeMax, Marze);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using [Math.Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Min_System_Double_System_Double_) & [Math.Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Max_System_Double_System_Double_)

```
realStopMax = Math.Max(realStopMax, realStop);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Max(...)` and `Math.Min(...)` should do the trick.

You can use them like so:

`realStopMin = Math.Min(realStop, Marze);`

The above code returns the lower of the two values. Vice versa applies for max.

Comment: `Math.max` and `Math.min` (lower case function names) are not valid C#. You may be confusing the C# version (`Math.Max` and `Math.Min`) with the Javascript version

Comment: Yep, sorry. Haven't used C# in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could Either use `Math.Max()` and `Math.Min()` like:

```
double min = Math.Min(realStopMin, realStop);
double max = Math.Max(realStopMax, realStop);
```

or

```
double min = realStopMin < realStop ? realStopMin : realStop;
double max = realStopMax > realStop ? realStopMax : realStop;
```

Also, I get the impression from the variable names that only `realStop` is changing and you set it to `realStopMax` if it is bigger than `realStopMax`. If this is true, so just an If would do it:

```
if(realStop > realStopMax) realStopMax = realStop;
if(realStop < realStopMin) realStopMin = realStop;
```